# Using Lombok @SLF4J annotation - how to add a date\time at the beginning of the log line?

Tags: java, logging, slf4j, lombok

While using Lombok's @Slf4j annotation on my classes, the log lines are missing date and time at the beginning of each one of them.
How can I add those to the lines?

```
@Slf4j
public abstract class DataScriptTestBase<T> extends CommonTestBase {
```

Thank you

Comment: By writing the proper pattern in your log configuration. SLF4J is a wrapper not a logging implementation. So it depends on your actual implementation.

Comment: What logging implementation are you using? You need to configure implementation itself

Comment: @M.Deinum (and geobreze). If that so, how come I can use simply Slf4j instead of, for example. log4j which is also available in Lombok? Does it mean that Slf4j supplies a basic log and if I need a more advanced logs I will need to use, log4j, log4j2, etc. ?

Comment: SLF4J is an API for unified logging, it then delegates to the actual implementation (log4j, jul, logback etc). If you only add `slf4j-api` nothing will happen as there is no actual implementation (only an API).

Comment: @M.Deinum So, I need to add for example log4j.properties file ?

Comment: If log4j is what you are using yes. Although I wouldn't recommend using Log4j but rather something newer like Log4j2 or Logback instead.

Comment: Yes, log4j was just an example. And does that also mean that I need to replace the slf4j lombock annotation with log4j2 lombock annotation?

Comment: No, you still can use the Slf4j annotation, it will use Slf4j for the logging calls, which will then delegate to the used implementation.

Answer (score 0):

1. Replace `@Slf4j` with `@Log4j`
2. Add log items in your code wherever you need it - `log.info("this is a test log message")`
3. Create log4j.xml file
4. Put it in the `/resources` dir
5. Run test suite
6. Navigate to the `/target/log4j-logs` and locate created log file

File example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="WARN">
  <Properties>
    <Property name="basePath">./target/log4j-logs</Property>
  </Properties>
  <Appenders>
    <RollingFile name="File" fileName="${basePath}/printlogs.log" filePattern="${basePath}/printlogs__%d{yyyy-MM-dd_HH-mm-ss}.log" append="false">
      <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} %-5level - %msg%n"/>
      <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="10000 MB" />
    </RollingFile>
    <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
      <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} %-5level - %msg%n"/>
    </Console>
  </Appenders>
  <Loggers>
    <Root level="info">
      <AppenderRef ref="File"/>
    </Root>
  </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```